# Was Naori Uchiha the creator of Izanami?

Tags: naruto

During the fight between Itachi-Sasuke and Kabuto Yakushi, we learnt about [Izanami](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Izanami) and its origin. Itachi explained that Izanami was created to counter the effect of [Izanagi](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Izanagi) by throwing the illusions of Izanagi in a loop. We also learnt that Izanagi was a powerful jutsu which was mostly abused by clansmen. We see in a flashback that there was a war between clan members where shinobis were fighting with each other and defeating them with Izanagi. The last survivor was [Naka Uchiha](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Naka_Uchiha) who was confronted by another comrade, [Naori Uchiha](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Naori_Uchiha). She used Izanami on him and was able to help him realize his mistake and made him accept the fate. Naori broke the cast and she became blind for the rest of her life.

The question is did she learned a new jutsu just to break Izanagi? Did she learnt about Izanagi's loophole and created an ultimate jutsu to overcome Izanagi? Maybe she did, she was seeing everyone abusing Izanagi and so she created an even more powerful jutsu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although never explicitly mentioned here's a possible explanation. Before that however, there are a couple things to consider.

- Firstly, the cost/consequence of using either technique leads the caster's sharingan to loose its light immidiately
- Secondly, Both techniques enable users to change reality. In the case of [Izanagi](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Izanagi), the illusion is applied onto reality itself. While in the case of [Izanami](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Izanami), the caster is able to put an individual in an almost sentient never ending illusion which becomes the reality of the opponent, continiously, until some trigger is met. (i.e the opponent either changes their ways or is trapped in an eternal loop)

Now the point I'm trying to make here is that I believe that the Izanami is a variation of the Izanagi which attempts to save a person by creating a repeating loop of specific events until some criteria is met. Thinking about it in the broad sense it still classifies as changing reality but only for the opponent because it will always work regardless of the opponents 5 senses, even if they know its an illusion.

So yea I believe she is the creator of Izanami, nevertheless, considering the similarities both have. It seems to me that she creatively used the Izanagi to such a degree that was completely unthought of (using it to help an individual change and thus creating a variation of the izanagi to stop the izanagi hence the izanami).